# Find the number of $6$-digit integers in which there are exactly $3$ even and $3$ odd digits

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of $6$-digit integers in which there are exactly $3$ even and $3$ odd digits.

In this question, I am getting $64800$ as the answer, but it's when I considered that a digit can be used only once.  I am not able to do it when repetition of digits is allowed.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  As a suggestion:  I'd first ignore the implied condition that the first digit be non-zero.  Easier to count if you ignore that.  Then count those with first digit $0$ and subtract.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for numbers in the range $100000-999999$. The positions of the odd numbers can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways and there are $5$ valid odd numbers and $5$ valid even numbers. This gives
$$\binom{6}{3}\cdot 5^3\cdot 5^3=312500$$
ways to do this. But this includes the cases where the first number is $0$. There are $31250$ cases with leading number $0$, since the positions of the $3$ odd numbers can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways and each position has $5$ possible numbers:
$$\binom{5}{3}\cdot 5^3\cdot 5^2=31250$$
The answer is the difference between $312500$ and $31250$.

Answer (score 1):

Break into cases:  Either the first digit is even, or it is not.

In the case that the first digit is even, pick which additional two more of the remaining five spaces are also occupied by even digits.

Then from left to right, pick which integer is used in each respective location.  There are $4$ choices for the first even integer (*since we specified it is a 6 digit integer, not a 6 digit string, it is heavily implied that a leading zero isn't allowed*), then there are $5$ choices for the next even integer and $5$ choices for the next, similarly there are $5$ choices for each of the odd integers as well.

Applying the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) then, we multiply the number of options available for each to get a total count for this case.

> There are $\binom{5}{2}\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5=10\cdot 4\cdot 5^5=125000$ six digit integers which start with an even number that has three even and three odd integers.

We approach similarly for the second case where the first digit is not even and then add the results together.

> Giving a final count of $\binom{5}{2}\cdot4\cdot5^5+\binom{5}{2}\cdot 5^6$

Answer (score 1):

there are ${6\choose 3} 5^6$ six digit numbers with  3 even and 3 odd digits allowing for the possibility that $0$ is the leading digit.

Each leading digit is equally likely.

${6\choose 3} 5^6 \frac {9}{10}$ will exclude those with $0$ as the leading digit.